# Converting an $n$-connected space into an $n$-reduced simplicial set

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

For an $n$-connected simplicial set (or simplicial complex), does there exist an $n$-reduced simplicial set (that is, having the $n$-skeleton of a point) of the same homotopy type?

If yes, can it be constructed algorithmically from a given finite simplicial complex (assuming that we can explicitly contract each loop/sphere of dim $\leq n$ in the original space, if necessary)?

I aked this first on [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999744/converting-a-1-connected-simplicial-complex-into-a-1-reduced-simplicial-set) but got no reply even after a bounty.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg+subcomplex

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks for the reference.